# Make config parameters persistent after HANA restart

Tags: hana

Each time our HANA DB goes down and comes back up, there are some two parameters that we normally run manually after it is started. I want to write a shell script to automate the execution of these queries when the database restarts.

Any ideas? Here are the two parameters.

```
ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('global.ini','SYSTEM') 
    SET('persistence','use_helper_threads_for_flush')='true' WITH RECONFIGURE;
ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('global.ini','SYSTEM') 
    SET ('persistence','use_helper_threads_for_flush')='false' WITH RECONFIGURE;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share what you have tried so far in order to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug described in [SAP Note 2655468](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2655468) covering three persistence parameters, and particularly `use_helper_threads_for_flush`, they have no effect after HANA restart. This is not a normal behavior, since parameters applied with a `ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION WITH RECONFIGURE` are active immediately and shouldn't be re-applied.

The workaround here is to re-set the parameter each time HANA restarts or upgrade your HANA release >= 032.00 (SPS03) or higher.

Possible way of automating this is through `hdbsql`. For example, create new Upstart job (`/etc/init`) on your HANA server and put these commands in it:

```
cd /hana/shared/<SID>/hdbclient
su - hdbadm
hdbsql -n localhost -i 00 -u AUSERADMIN -p APassword01
hdbsql -u AUSERADMIN -p APassword01 "ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('global.ini','SYSTEM') SET('persistence','use_helper_threads_for_flush')='true' WITH RECONFIGURE"
hdbsql -u AUSERADMIN -p APassword01 "ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('global.ini','SYSTEM') SET('persistence','use_helper_threads_for_flush')='false' WITH RECONFIGURE"
```

However, I do not recommend doing this and better stick to upgrade.

Note, that this parameter is internal and shouldn't be used outside of scope of [note 2655238](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2655238)